# Twitter 4j - Get tweets by user ID - Processing

Tags: twitter, processing, twitter4j

There seems to be many different tutorials and examples out there to allow for tweets to be pulled into Processing from one specific user.

And yet I'm still having problems getting any code to work. I have managed to get tweets by searching with hashtags, so the twitter4j library (latest) is working within Processing (also latest software). I still a complete coding novice...

I've found the following code to do exactly what I need, but unfortunately it isn't complete, where I'm assuming you need to declare your Consumer Keys and Access tokens... But I've no idea how to do this with this code. Is this something that someone is able to provide and explain?

Essentially, I need the full sketch... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Code from elsewhere:

```js
  final Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_KEY_SECRET);
    AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(TWITTER_TOKEN,
            TWITTER_TOKEN_SECRET);
    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
    try {
        Status status = twitter.showStatus(Long.parseLong(tweetID));
        if (status == null) { // 
            // don't know if needed - T4J docs are very bad
        } else {
            System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName()
                        + " - " + status.getText());
        }
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        System.err.print("Failed to search tweets: " + e.getMessage());
        // e.printStackTrace();
        // DON'T KNOW IF THIS IS THROWN WHEN ID IS INVALID
    }
```

EDIT: This is how I've added the consumer/access keys - is this right?

```
 twitter.setOAuthConsumer("MyConsumerKey", "MyConsumerSecret");
AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken("MyAccessToken", "MyAccessTokenSecret");
twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
```

EDIT2: This is what I have now to get the User's tweets. But produced the error: 'cannot convert from ResponseList to Status'

```
    String user="USER ID";

final Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer("MY CONSUMER KEY", "MY CONSUMER KEY SECRET");
AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken("MY TWITTER TOKEN", "MY TWITTER     TOKEN SECRET");
twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
try {

    Status status = twitter.getUserTimeline(user); 
    if (status == null) { // 
        // don't know if needed - T4J docs are very bad
    } else {
        System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName()
                    + " - " + status.getText());

    }
} catch (TwitterException e) {
    System.err.print("Failed to search tweets: " + e.getMessage());
    // e.printStackTrace();
    // DON'T KNOW IF THIS IS THROWN WHEN ID IS INVALID
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need first to create a twitter app, to do so go to https://apps.twitter.com/, from there you can get all the infos needed to get your credentials.

in your code just replace the 'CONSUMER_KEY','CONSUMER_KEY_SECRET','Access Token','Access Token Secret' by the credentials.

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
                .setOAuthConsumerKey("XXXXX")
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXXXXX")
                .setOAuthAccessToken("XXXX-XXXXX")
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("XXXXXXX");
```

hope this help!

Comment: Hi Mounir Elfassi!

Tried adding in the keys. But now I'm getting an error that reads:

Cannot find anything named "tweetID"

Also, I've added the amended part of the code to the original post. Is that the right way to add the keys?

Comment: My bad! Just realised that this is where you can put the ID of a tweet and get that specific tweet into Processing. However, how can I remove this part and where would I place the USER ID instead? :)

Comment: if the problem solved you have to mark it as "Solved", to get the user ID type the Username in this website http://gettwitterid.com/.

Comment: i have edited my answer of how to use the credentials, XXXX is the their value

Comment: Without adding the code you've added to your original comment - The keys seem to working in the way I mentioned previously... But the only thing that's stopping this questions from being solved now is the fact that the code is set up to retrieve a specific tweet by the TWEET ID.

I know how to get the ID of a Twitter user (Thanks though :)) - But what I need now, for this to work, is to know where to put the USER ID in order to get a User's tweets.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in this line "Status status = twitter.showStatus(Long.parseLong(tweetID));"

Comment: replace it by: Status status = twitter.getUserTimeline(user);

Comment: and String user = "username";

Comment: Thanks for your patience so far!! - Made the changes, but now I'm getting the error: 'Cannot convert from ResponseList<Status> to Status.... 
Any thoughts?
I've added the code I have now as another Edit to my original post. Thank you for looking at this!!